# Change title to username in HTML

Tags: html, node.js, authentication

I'm building a web application in Node and using passport js for user authentication. I was wondering how you change a title in the header after a user has logged in. Here's what it looks like now:

```
        <div id="loginname">
            <a href="/login">Login</a>
        </div>
```

After a user signs in, I want "Login" to change to their username with an href that leads to their profile. How do I do this?

Comment: jquery? c#? do you have the username already?

Comment: jquery. No, I don't have the username already.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a single page app? It seems like this should not be on the page that is loaded after login. However, here is a way to change this element using js by adding an element id.

```
<div id="loginname">
    <a id="some-id-here" href="/login">Login</a>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("some-id-here").href = 'some-link-here';
    document.getElementById("some-id-here").innerHTML = 'username here';
</script>
```

or if you are using jQuery you can you this script

```
<script>
    $('#some-id-here').href = 'some-link-here';
    $('#some-id-here').innerHTML = 'username here';
</script>
```

Comment: I used the element id code and it redirects the "Login" link to the profile after I sign in. But it still shows "Login" instead of the username in the header.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, this needs to be turned into an object before you can use the .innerHTML method. Use ` $('#some-id-here')[0].innerHTML = 'username here'; ` instead